# How to generate BinarySecurityToken (X509PKIPathv1) from .p12 file

Tags: c#, ws-security

I am trying to consume a Java web service from a C# client. The service requires `BinarySecurityToken` element with value type `X509PKIPathv1`.

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1">
      MIIH......
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Since [WCF does not support X509PKIPathv1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/security-protocols#12-x509-token) value type, I am generating the SOAP message by hand, signing it using the `SignedXml` class, encrypting it using the `EncryptedXml` and sending it using the `WebClient` class. As for the value of `BinarySecurityToken` element, I used the value generated in SoapUI for the same certificate, and it works.

But, I would like to be able to generate this value programmatically from .p12 file, and not having to paste it from SoapUI again every time when the certificate expires.

The [WS-Security documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss-m/wss/v1.1.1/os/wss-x509TokenProfile-v1.1.1-os.html) is a bit vague, so I am not sure how to go about it. This is all the information it gives about this token type:

> **#X509PKIPathv1**: An ordered list of X.509 certificates packaged in a PKIPath

How to generate this value from .p12 file in C#? SoapUI does it somehow.

Comment: I have this exact same question, except from a C++/OpenSSL perspective.

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be a fully solution to your problem but it may help you out somewhat.

This:

> **#X509PKIPathv1**: An ordered list of X.509 certificates packaged in a PKIPath

means is a asn1 sequence or chain of certificates that you have used to sign your message. You can even see it [here](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/x509/X509CertPath.html#X509CertPath(iaik.x509.X509Certificate[])).

To give some context [asn1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) is way of representing data in way independent of the machine you are using. This data is binary and not human readable so you transform it to bade 64 and that is what you see in that field.

I am not entirely sure what the exact content of your `.p12` file is but at the very least I assume it has the certificate of the private key you used to sign your message and maybe the chain until the publicly trusted certificate or [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

I am mostly a C++ developer and I know openssl provides a C like api to read a certificate [manipulate the underlying asn1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/d2i_X509_REQ_bio.html) structure and the output it as a string.

Sorry for not providing with a greater level of detail or a code example